# What's the alternative for kSecTrustResultConfirm in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, mknetworkkit, mknetworkengine

Our old app uses MKNetworkKit and MKNetworkOperation.

Now under iOS 7 `kSecTrustResultConfirm` is deprecated.
In MKNetworkOperation, there is this code:

```
 else if(result == kSecTrustResultConfirm) { // DEPRECATED

          if(self.shouldContinueWithInvalidCertificate) {

            // Cert not trusted, but user is OK with that
            DLog(@"Certificate is not trusted, but self.shouldContinueWithInvalidCertificate is YES");
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
          } else {

            DLog(@"Certificate is not trusted, continuing without credentials. Might result in 401 Unauthorized");
            [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
          }
        }
```

is there replacement for `kSecTrustResultConfirm`?

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it?

Comment: Documentation reference: 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kSecTrustResultConfirm

Comment: I believe you no longer need to check for this case in iOS 7 as this value is never returned.  In short the block of code that is conditional on this COULD be #ifdef'd and ignored.  Not sure though. Still trying to wrap my head around the whole API.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update MKNetworkKit for whatever reason, check out this commit: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit/commit/c28959805991bb8f0e99ede9c822e985b41f6fc9 . You'll see that the `kSecTrustResultConfirm` conditional has been deleted completely, and you should be able to do the same.